# Gtk New Tool Bar Button from GtkImage

Tags: c, gtk

Provided here is an example of how to create a GtkToolItem from a GtkImage, using gtk_tool_button_new.  I'm posting this since there is not explicit example that I could find.

```c
GError *gerror = NULL;
GdkPixbuf *pixbuf_AND = gdk_pixbuf_new_from_file("images/AND.png", &gerror);
if (gerror != NULL)
    printf ("error = %s \r\n", gerror->message);

GtkImage *image_AND = gtk_image_new_from_file ((gchar *)"images/AND.png");
GdkPixbuf *pixbuf_AND1 = gtk_image_get_pixbuf  (image_AND);

GtkImage *image_AND1 = gtk_image_new_from_pixbuf ((GdkPixbuf *) pixbuf_AND);


GtkToolItem *toolbar_AND = gtk_tool_button_new ((GtkImage *) image_AND, "AND");
printf ("size = (%i,%i) \r\n", 
    gdk_pixbuf_get_width (pixbuf_AND1), gdk_pixbuf_get_width (pixbuf_AND1));

g_signal_connect(G_OBJECT(toolbar_AND), "clicked", 
        G_CALLBACK(mnuNode_And_Selected), "menu.node.and");

gtk_toolbar_insert(GTK_TOOLBAR(toolbar), toolbar_AND, -1);
gtk_widget_show ((GtkWidget *) toolbar_AND);
gtk_widget_show (GTK_WIDGET(image_AND));

// ==============================================

char cwd[1024];
    if (getcwd(cwd, sizeof(cwd)) != NULL)
       fprintf(stdout, "Current working dir: %s\n", cwd);
    else
       perror("getcwd() error");
```

Or the short version, without all the checking and rechecking ...

```c
GtkImage *image_AND = gtk_image_new_from_file ((gchar *)"images/AND.png");
GtkToolItem *toolbar_AND = gtk_tool_button_new ((GtkImage *) image_AND, "AND");

g_signal_connect(G_OBJECT(toolbar_AND), "clicked", 
        G_CALLBACK(mnuNode_And_Selected), "menu.node.and");

gtk_toolbar_insert(GTK_TOOLBAR(toolbar), toolbar_AND, -1);
gtk_widget_show ((GtkWidget *) toolbar_AND);
gtk_widget_show (GTK_WIDGET(image_AND));
```

I hope that this helps other trying to build similar projects.

Comment: Hi, this may be a bit of an odd request if you're new to Stack Overflow, but could you rephrase this in the form of a question and answer? See http://blog.stackoverflow.com/2011/07/its-ok-to-ask-and-answer-your-own-questions/ That allows someone else who may have another answer in the future to contribute it as well, and fits better with the "collaborative knowledge" nature of this site. Thanks for documenting your knowledge here!